# selectedindex of list in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

[this is the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0uM4.png)

well i want to test which value is selected in both `wilaya` and `activité sportives` as exemple if the selected one is football show a certain message so i tried to get the selected value that way in both

```
if (ins.wilaya.selectedIndex=="Sétif")
alert("vous avez choisi Sétif");
```

`ins` is the `form` name and `wilaya` is `select` name 
it didn't work
is there another way to get those value?
HTML CODE

```
 <select id="wilaya_list" name="wilaya">
                    <option Value="Setif">Sétif</option>
                    <option Value="BBA">BBA</option>
                    <option Value="M'sila">M'sila</option>
                    <option Value="Batna">Batna</option>
                    <option Value="Mila">Mila</option>
                    <option Value="Autre">Autre</option>
```

Comment: what is selectedIndex.?

Comment: it is supposed to  return the selected value

Comment: selectedIndex is an integer value, representing the index of the selected value. While the selectedValue is the property that holds the text value of the item.

Comment: Please share a minimum example with HTML.

Comment: Whats wrong with just `ins.wilaya.value === 'Setif'`?

Comment: @putvande 
It worked thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this fix the issue?

```
if (ins.wilaya[ins.wilaya.selectedIndex].value =="Sétif")
alert("vous avez choisi Sétif");
```